# find a function such that $f''(x) = -f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

find a function $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k} x^{k}  $, converges on $\mathbb R$ and  :

1. $f(0) = 1$.
2. $f'(0) = 1$
3. **$f''(x) = -f(x)$ for all x$\in \mathbb R $**

I tried it with the function sinh(x) but failed miserably because $f'(0) = 0$ and $f''(x) = f(x)$ and not $f''(x) = -f(x)$, help !!

Comment: You are very close with $f(x) = \sinh(x)$ – just remove one letter!

Comment: @MartinR it fails the other conditions however

Comment: @MartinR but sin(0) is not 1

Comment: Play with $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ ... But perhaps the goal is to determine the coefficients $a_k$ from the differential equation?

Comment: i also tried : cos(x) - sin(x)

Comment: $\cos x +\sin x$ does the trick. Just solve the last differential equation and get $A\cos x+B\sin x$ and find A, B using the initial conditions.

Comment: I would suggest that you might be being invited to work with the sum and plug that into the various equations to determine the coefficients - there is no point in starting like that otherwise. Otherwise, rather than guessing, there is a technique for solving such equations which involves finding two independent solutions of $3.$ and then using linearity to combine them in a way which satisfies the two boundary conditions.

Comment: @MarkBennet thank you for your help , I learned this two days ago and I am still a beginner , thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply by asking "what are the functions which, upon differentiating twice, return the negative of themselves?" you may be able to reason that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ work, at which point you just need to combine them correctly so as to satisfy the "initial" conditions.

However, it is likely more in the spirit of the problem to insert the power series into the differential equation and try to solve for the coefficients. If we put $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$ into the equation, we find that $$\sum^\infty_{k=2} k(k-1)a_k x^{k-2} = - \sum^\infty_{k=0} a_k x^{k}.$$ By reindexing the first sum, we see this is the same as $$\sum^\infty_{k=0}(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2} x^k = - \sum^\infty_{k=0} a_k x^k.$$ This shows that $$a_{k+2} = -\frac{a_{k}}{(k+2)(k+1)}.$$ Using this relation, along with $a_0 = a_1 = 1$ (which come from $f(0) = f'(0) = 1$), you can show that $$a_{2n} = \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, a_{2m+1} = \frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)!}.$$ Then after splitting into even and odd terms, you can recognize these as the coefficients of the power series for $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ respectively.

Comment: thanks a lot i am trying to get used to dealing with  power series but from a functional perspective and this will really help me achieve that !

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ then it staifies all the conditions .